# Why are my inline-block elements being positioned underneath one another?

Tags: html, css

My `.image_series` class has the attribute `inline-block` set to it. If this is the case, why are my elements appearing below one another? This behaviour doesn't make sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/mH5Be/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `inline-block` Elements had a `width` of 85% (that's 85% of the parent element width!) - and 2 elements that big won't fit next to each other by definition.

Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/mH5Be/1/